# How to display JSON parse errors?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a front-end log in page which aims to parse JSON messages. Its logic is:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form_login').ajaxForm(function(response) {
    $("#content").html(response.message);
    if(response.result == 0) {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = response.lnkmember;
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that if there is a typo or error in back-end PHP then front-end is unable to display those errors or inform users. It appears hanging but when I open development tools on Chrome I could see following network data is indeed transferred back.

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: email_support in <b>technical\public_html\email.php</b> on line <b>57</b><br />
Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.
{"result":"2", "message":"An internal error occurred. Our technical staff has been informed to fix this. Sorry for any inconvenience."}
```

In back-end I did use try-catch logic and will return a non-zero field 'result' in the JSON reply. but if the php error is prepending json message then front-end is unhappy.

The most satisfactory solution would be send PHP error to technical support while displaying only my JSON message to user. but I have no idea how to achieve this. Can you please help me out then?

Comment: So why do you access undefined variables in php at first place?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly catch your own error message and I woul try to pass back the erroneous JSON to the client as a string:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form_login').ajaxForm(function(response) {

            if ( response.result == 2 ) {
               // handle error
               console.log(response.message);
               console.log(response.originalJSON);
            } else {

                $("#content").html(response.message);
                if(response.result == 0) {
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                      window.location.href = response.lnkmember;
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

And together with the message, you pass back the sent JSON string:

```
    {"result":"2", 
     "message":"An internal error occurred. Our technical staff has been informed to fix this. Sorry for any inconvenience."
     "originalJSON":" .... stringyfied JSON from the PHP ...." }
```

**EDIT**
On the PHP side, you may catch JSON errors this way:

```
    $json_parsed = json_decode($json_string, true);

    if ( hasJSONerror() !== false )
    {
        // output json_string
        return;
    }
    ....

    function hasJSONerror()
    {
        // Define the possible JSON errors.
        $json_errors = array(
          JSON_ERROR_NONE => 'No error has occurred',
          JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'The maximum stack depth has been exceeded',
          JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded',
          JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error',
          JSON_ERROR_UTF8 => 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'
        );
        if ( json_last_error() != 0 )
        {

            return json_last_error();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: due to the notice message, the response is invalid JSON - don't believe it would actually get parsed in order to access `response.message`

Answer (score 0):

Due to the actual difficulty of parsing warnings or notices from the response in PHP (actual errors would lead to a 500 response header, which is easily catchable), my personal take for production is to actually tell PHP to disable all displayed warnings for this page.

So, on this PHP script, right at the top, add :

```
error_reporting(E_NONE);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

This will disable any error output from PHP for this page, allowing you to handle them.

**Do note:** It would be ***much*** better to simply make sure no such warnings occur in production!!! If there is a point of ambiguity where you feel you cannot handle (there shouldn't be), you can always silence PHP with the `@` symbol.

Comment: "This will disable any error output from PHP for this page, allowing you to handle them." --- that's wrong. `display_errors` setting has nothing to do with catch'ability of them. And the part of the answer about `@` is simply harmful.

Comment: @zerkms : The question is not about catchability - it demonstrates that JSON is returned containing an error code and message, but is not parsed due to the warnings present. Hence my answer.

Comment: I only addressed a particular part of your answer: "This will disable any error output from PHP for this page, allowing you to handle them." which is just wrong. `display_errors` does not allow or prevent something to be handled. The best idea not to disable errors output but just fix them.

Comment: @zerkms: From the PHP manual for "display_errors": "This determines whether errors should be printed to the screen as part of the output or if they should be hidden from the user.". The question is about hiding the error from output, allowing JSON to be parsed - not completely.

Comment: Well, "not print" error != "handle" it. Just because you've hidden something does not mean you handled it. "The question is about hiding the error from output" --- no it's not. Simply hiding it is a stupid solution. One should just not access the not defined variable ever, then this error would have never occurred.

Comment: @zerkms: kindly read the question again. The question is about an error being handled via try...catch, which correctly generates a JSON response about an error being present. However, since PHP also prints a warning in the generated output, it is never parsed clientside. Hence, the need to hide it from output.

Comment: "since PHP also prints a warning in the generated output, it is never parse clientside. Hence, the need to hide it from output" --- read my comment once again: it's a **STUPID** solution that you suggest. You should **FIX THE MISTAKE** not pretend there is no such in the code.

Comment: @zerkms: as I've suggested in the footnote of my answer, I agree with you. This is a workaround for a problem that should not occur.

Comment: So, if you understand that why don't you give the proper answer instead? Like, why to teach newbies to do stupid things at all? And the footnote is actually even worse than the beginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77431/discussion-between-hexblot-and-zerkms).